# Comboboxes show items in Netbeans, but are empty in Jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a working Java form application that I have made in Netbeans; it contains 8 comboboxes which each contain a different number of items. When I run this form in Netbeans, the items appear and I am able to interact with them, but when I run the jar file that I generated, the comboboxes are all empty.

Comment: Show code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm not really able to do that, but I can say that the comboboxes are being filled using a map which gets the inputs from csv files

Comment: Then check if your data structures are as expected when you construct the model for the Comboboxes. If resources are involved give them an extra look.

Comment: I put the csv files in the dist folder and it works, thank you for your help!

Comment: You should strongly consider improving your error reporting

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this